# trouble sending mail using phpmailer in localhost XAMPP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

hello guys i'm trying to sending mail in my localhost using phpmailer. whenever i run the code it appears an error like this :

> Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

i already tried to change php.ini file uncomment the "extension=php_openssl.dll"  and i even tried to changed it to 587 but it didn't work.

```
<?php
    $mailto = $_POST['mail_to'];
    $mailSub = $_POST['mail_sub'];
    $mailMsg = $_POST['mail_msg'];
   require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail ->IsSmtp();
   $mail ->SMTPDebug = 0;
   $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $mail ->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail ->Port = 465; //587
   $mail ->IsHTML(true);
   $mail ->Username = "mygmail@gmail.com";
   $mail ->Password = "mypassword";
   $mail ->SetFrom("mygmail@gmail.com");
   $mail ->Subject = $mailSub;
   $mail ->Body = $mailMsg;
   $mail ->AddAddress($mailto);

   if(!$mail->Send())
   {
       echo "Mail Not Sent";
       echo "<br>";
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Mail Sent";
   }
```

please help me solve this problem guys

Comment: did you do the necessary changes in your gmail account?

Comment: nope i didn't change anything in my gmail account. but i haven't tried using other account.

Comment: you need to turn on the setting that says "verify less secure apps" on gmail

Comment: I am posting this as answer too :-)

Comment: Better to fix the actual problem rather than avoiding it, as detailed in the troubleshooting guide you apparently ignored.

Comment: You’re also using an obsolete version of PHPMailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue when setting up a webserver or website to send over SMTP via gmail.

If you provisioned the gmail account, be sure to turn on the setting that says "verify less secure apps" on gmail. Refer to this blog post with screenshots indicating where to configure this: http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-fix-gmail-authentication-issues/